# Multiple IPV4 address

Tags: ipv4

The IPV4 address is exhausted and IPV6 is being deployed.  My question is why should some interface be provided with multiple IPV4 addresses ?  If one interface is restricted with one IP address then would not that be efficient usage of limited resources ?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can have multiple IPv4 addresses since one interface can host many things. A single physical server can host many virtual servers. Each virtual server can have its own public facing IPv4. There is a lot of inefficient usage of IPv4 addresses. Companies and universities that started using IPv4 early on own huge address blocks but might only have a few public facing IPv4 addresses in use. They are a limited resource which is why we are moving to IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that people use multiple addresses on one interface is for protocols that don't support some kind of virtual-host function.

For example it used to be normal to have a separate IP address for each website in the HTTP/0.9 times. Then virtual hosting became possible with HTTP/1.0, but not for SSL, so most websites on one server started sharing an IP address except for SSL enabled websites. And now with SSL-SNI even that is not necessary anymore.

But there are still other protocols that don't support virtual hosting multiple instances on one IP address. So even though putting multiple addresses on one interface is less common than it used to be, the need for it hasn't disappeared completely.